# Pass different classes as argument to a member function in c++

Tags: c++, oop

I would like to pass different classes as an argument to a function, but I am not sure how to do it in c++. The classes I want to pass have member functions with the same name. I wrote my program in `JavaScript`:

```
class Calculator {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    // here I want to pass in AddCommand and SubtractCommand class types
    executeCommand(command) {
        this.value = command.execute(this.value); // They both have .execute methods
    }
}

class AddCommand {
    constructor(valueToAdd) {
        this.valueToAdd = valueToAdd;
    }

    execute(currValue) {
        return currValue + this.valueToAdd;
    }

    undo(currValue) {
        return currValue - this.valueToAdd;
    }
}

class SubtractCommand {
    constructor(valueToSubtract) {
        this.valueToSubtract = valueToSubtract;
    }

    execute(currValue) {
        return currValue - this.valueToSubtract;
    }

    undo(currValue) {
        return currValue + this.valueToSubtract;
    }
}
```

As you can see my `AddCommand` and `SubtractCommand` classes both have `execute` member functions, and I want to pass instances of them to the `executeCommand` method in the `Calculator` class. How should I do it? I know the example might be trivial, but I am just asking how to deal with a case like this in general.

I can perform add and subtract like this:

```
let calculator = new Calculator(0);

calculator.executeCommand(new AddCommand(5));
console.log(calculator.value); // 5

calculator.executeCommand(new SubtractCommand(5));
console.log(calculator.value); // 0
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are the classes that provide this `execute` function intended to share a common base class or interface? In that case you could pass a pointer or reference to that. Or you could try turning the `executeCommand` function into a template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few different to ways to tackle this problem depending on the specific needs of your program.

Here are the two techniques that are most commonly used:

### 1. Compile-time polymorphism with templates

This is appropriate, and generally preferable, when the type of the command is known at the call site. It involves making `executeCommand()` a function template, i.e a function that produces multiple implementations "on-demand" based on the arguments passed to it.

In modern (c++20) C++, you can use a concept to make the expected interface explicit. In older versions of the language, you would make the `executeCommand()` method accept any type and just use it as if the required methods are implemented. This is called duck-typing.

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template<typename T>
concept Command = requires(const T& cmd, int v) {
  { cmd.execute(v) } -> std::convertible_to<int>;
  { cmd.undo(v) } -> std::convertible_to<int>; 
};

class Calculator {
   int value;
public:
    Calculator(int v) : value(v) {}

    template<Command CmdT>
    void executeCommand(const CmdT& command) {
        value = command.execute(value);
    }

    // For C++17 and earlier:
    // template<typename CmdT>
    // void executeCommand(const CmdT& command) {
    //     value = command.execute(value);
    // }

};

class AddCommand {
    int valueToAdd;
public:
    AddCommand(int v) : valueToAdd(v){}

    int execute(int currValue) const {
        return currValue + valueToAdd;
    }

    int undo(int currValue) const {
        return currValue - valueToAdd;
    }
};

int main() {
  Calculator calc{0};

  AddCommand command{3};

  calc.executeCommand(command);
}
```

### 2. Runtime Polymorphism with virtual methods.

This is appropriate if the actual type of the command is erased by the time it's used. In this scenario, you declare a base interface class that the various implementations inherit from. Invoking the methods on pointers and references to the base class will call the subclass's implementations.

```cpp
class Command {
public:
  virtual ~Command() {}

  virtual int execute(int currValue) const = 0;
  virtual int undo(int currValue) const = 0;
};

class Calculator {
   int value;
public:
    Calculator(int v) : value(v) {}

    void executeCommand(const Command& command) {
        value = command.execute(value);
    }
};

class AddCommand final : public Command {
    int valueToAdd;
public:
    AddCommand(int v) : valueToAdd(v) {}

    int execute(int currValue) const override {
        return currValue + valueToAdd;
    }

    int undo(int currValue) const override {
        return currValue - valueToAdd;
    }
};

void process(const Command& cmd) {
  Calculator calc{0};
  calc.executeCommand(cmd);
}

int main() {
  AddCommand command{3};

  process(command);
}
```

Comment: how about `Polymorphism` -> `Runtime polymorphism`? 1 can be considered as some form of polymorphism too, while "polymorphism" is more general than 2  I was about to edit already but it inverleaved with your edit

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number fair enough.

Comment: @Frank Thanks a lot! I think compile-time polymorphism is what I need!